# Ubuntu Linux install

Tags: kubuntu

Please am trying to install Ubuntu alongside windows 8.1 but it stays on the screen without booting into the Ubuntu when I choose the try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu. Please can u help me because the last time I tried it told me I have exceeded the number of partitions. Please help me.

Comment: this may help you... http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: So, what did you try to do "last time", and how many partitions are there?